# How to use Perl script for testing Android applications using Eclipse Epic?

Tags: android, perl, testing, adb

I am working on Perl testing for an Android application. How to use Perl script for testing Android application using Eclipse Epic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

```
#use strict;
#use warnings;

system("adb shell am start -a com.android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList");

sleep(0);

system("adb shell am start -a com.android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");

system("adb shell input text 'Anji'");

sleep(2);

system("adb shell input keyevent 20");

sleep(2);

system("adb shell input text '9491407690'");

sleep(4);

system("adb shell input keyevent 21");

sleep(2);

system("adb shell input keyevent 66");

system("adb shell input keyevent 20");

system("adb shell input keyevent 20");

sleep(2);

system("adb shell input keyevent 66");

sleep(2);

system("adb shell input keyevent 19");

sleep(0);

system("adb shell input keyevent 66");

sleep(0);

system("adb shell input keyevent 5");

sleep(0);

system("adb shell input keyevent 4");

sleep(0);

system("adb shell input text 'callsuccess'");

sleep(4);

system("adb shell input keyevent 21");

system("adb shell input keyevent 66");

sleep(0);

system("adb shell input keyevent 19");

system("adb shell input keyevent 4");

system("adb shell input keyevent 4");

system("adb shell input keyevent 66");


system("adb shell am start -a com.android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.launcher/.Launcher");
```